# Provide a Single LWC to a User - Licensing & Design

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, licenses, lightning-out

I'm working on a use case where an organization uses Salesforce as it's primary desktop solution for it's employee base where the employees have a full Salesforce license.

A custom lightning web component (LWC) has been built to interact with customer data stored in an external API and leverages Salesforce profiles/roles to conditionally display content on the LWC. The LWC is displayed on the Contact object lightning page. The employees use this component LWC along with other Salesforce list views, console navigation, and typical Salesforce functionality.

However, as the business grows it will have associates (dozens to hundreds of users who may be internal or may be third-party vendors) who will also need to update this customer data and see some contact data, but will not need all of the other Salesforce functionality.

I'm looking to understand my options here as a full Salesforce license for a user to interact with an API and view a contact record is not very cost effective, but at the same time do not want to rebuild the LWC in a web app, build out authentication, and then have to manage two applications.

### Potential Options

##### Platform License + Salesforce Console

Summary: Use Salesforce Platform license and have users log in to Salesforce and leverage Salesforce console to access

Concern:

- I tried to use a Platform license, I can see the LWC on a custom lightning page, but cannot see any contact or other standard objects. (My understanding of documentation is platform license only allows access to custom object records).

##### Lightning Out + External App

Summary: Display LWC with [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.lightning_out) in an external app that leverages

Concern:

- I believe this would still require a full Salesforce license for the end user for authentication and standard object access (same licensing / object access concerns as platform) and I would have to manage an external app.

##### Partner Community Licenses + Community

Concerns:

- I do not have access to this license type in my org, but since some of the users in these groups are internal I'm wondering if it would be a conflict in licensing. Access wise, I believe in a community I could put an LWC on a page and share some contact, but the configuration of the community / experience page would be different and may require changes to the LWC to work on both community page and lightning page (for the existing full license users).

##### Single Salesforce Integration User + External App

Concerns:

- Provides cost savings, but still have to build some sort of app and authentication pattern to keep track of who is changing credentials since the server to server integration would not suffice  for the traceability requirements of which end-user pulled and updated customer data.

##### What I'm looking for?

Going to work with our Salesforce account managers as well, but wanted to see if others have had experience or any references to what the best practice is for this use case?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.users_internal_external_license_types.htm spells out the Experience Cloud licensing for internal vs external. The rest is a standard trade-off between cost of build/maintenance vs license.